# Regular expression to exclude alphabetic characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone suggest a correct regex pattern in angular 2 for accepting numbers and special charterers for angular 2 input field , excepting alphabets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has nothing to do with angular, but you can accomplish this with plain javascript.  The regexp object's `test` method returns a boolean showing whether or not your string matches the regular expression.

```
/^[^a-z]+$/i.test("!@#$%") == true  // true
/^[^a-z]+$/i.test("Hello") == true  // false
```

In this regex, the initial `^` is the beginning of line anchor and the trailing `$` is end of line. The rest of the expression matches 1 or more characters that's not alphabetical. The `i` flag at the end makes it case-insensitive.

There are a number of nice online regex testing tools. One is https://regex101.com/.

Comment: How do i restrict Both a-z and A-Z values , i am using this [Validators.pattern('[^a-zA_Z]+$')] but it doesnt work

Comment: That's what the `i` is for. Use the online tester.

Comment: And your example uses an underscore instead of a hyphen, which will not give you the results you want.

Comment: Also you probably want to have a `^` anchor at the front, or otherwise you'll get matches with stuff that ends in symbols but can still contain letters.

Comment: Thnks , it worked with this : [Validators.pattern('[^a-zA-Z]+$')]

Comment: @A4u... that's not correct. You probably need a leading `^`.  for example, the string "ABC$@!" will match your regex.